# OpenCV - Detection of moving object C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on Traffic Surveillance System an OpenCv project, I need to detect moving cars and people. I am using background subtraction method to detect moving objects and thus drawing counters. 
I have a problem :
When two car are moving on road closely them my system detects it as one car, I have used all efforts like canny-edge detection, transformation etc. Can anyone tell me any particular methodology to solve this type of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of solutions are possible.

A geometric approach would detect that the one moving blob is too big to be a single passenger car. Still, this may indicate a car with a caravan. That leads us to another question: if you have two blobs moving close together, how *do* you know it's two cars and not one car towing a caravan? You may need to add some elementary shape detection.

Another trivial approach is to observe that cars do not suddenly multiply. If you have 5 video frames, and in 4 of them you spot two cars, then it's very very likely that the 5th frame also has two cars.

Answer (score 0):

CV system tracks object as moving blobs (“clouds” of moving pixels) identifies them and distinct one from another in case of occlusions. When two (or more) blobs are intersected, system merges them in one combined object and marks it by IDs of all those source-objects that currently included in the combination. When one of objects separates from the combination CV system recognize which one is out and re-arrange ID appropriately.

Comment: Can post any link for the same ?

Comment: I don't know much about SVM machine learning , can you sugest me a tutorial , I need urgent help?

Comment: The behavior described in the text above appears to be a correct description of OpenCV object tracking, but this is **entirely** unrelated to SVM's and SciKit. Did you just copy a random link from the other answer?!